# Integrate / import firebase data into mongoDb in real time

Tags: mongodb, firebase, spring-boot

I've integrated firebase for sign in and otp in my android app. However I've developed backend using Java spring boot and mongoDb. All the images and data are in the backend. Is it possible to extract the firebase uid or sign in info automatically into mongoDb as soon as user signs up? I want to use firebase for signup and otp only since its too easy and quick. I don't know if its possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible via the Firebase Functions?
But another answer might be to do the following method:

```
User.getToken()
```

And use that for access to your mongo etc...?

Comment: Yeah after sign up, I store uid in mongodb, thats an option but I have to call firebase and again mongodb, it may be costly.

Comment: Yeah I think that is the problem with Firebase...it seems like a great idea at the time but it sort of ties you in. Did you look at functions...I seem to remember somewhere you can create triggers (but then you would need to call your mongoDB from Firebase)....Have you considered using something like Auth0?